# Access an application running on a random port in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

My application is running within a pod container in a kubernetes cluster. Every time it is started in the container it allocates a random port. I would like to access my application from outside (from another pod or node for example) but since it allocates a random port I cannot create a serivce (NodePort or LoadBalancer) to map the application port to a specific port to be able to access it.

What are the options to handle this case in a kubernetes cluster?

Comment: What do you mean by "it allocates a random port"? You define one or more ports in the podspec that your container listens on.

Comment: Pods are normally accessed via [Kubernetes Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) that give you a static and discoverable entry point into your pod(s).

Comment: @Robert Keck I mean it creates an application on a random port. I cannot use kubernetes services since I don't know the targetPort

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity: What kind of application doesn't let you configure the port?

Comment: quite complex to explain

Comment: @JackLehman can you give us some more details about the application?

Comment: Try use a port scanner like `nmap`, to scan all ports, and get those active one?

Comment: using `nmap` requires some manual steps which is inconvenient

Answer (score 2):

Not supported, checkout the issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/2611). Even with docker, if your range is overly broad, you can hit [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/11185) as well.

Comment: I hoped there will be a trick to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

One option to solve this would be to use a dynamically configured sidecar proxy that takes care of routing the pods traffic from a fixed port to the dynamic port of the application.

[image]

This has the upside that the service can be scaled even if all instances have different ports.
But this also has the potentially big downside that every request has an added overhead due to the extra network step and even if it's just some milliseconds this can have quite an impact depending on how the application works.

Regarding the dynamic configuration of the proxy you could e.g. use shared pod volumes.

**Edit:**

Containers within a pod are a little bit special. They are able to share predefined volumes and their network namespace.

For **shared volumes** this means. you are able to define a volume e.g. of type emptyDir and mount it in both containers. The result is that you can share information between both containers by writing them into that specific volume in the first pod and reading the information in the second.

For **networking** this makes communication between containers of one pod easier because you can use the loopback to communicate with between your containers. In your case this means the sidecar proxy container can call your service by calling *localhost:<dynamic-port>*.

For further information take a look at the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#resource-sharing-and-communication).

**So how is this going to help you?**

You can use a proxy like [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) and configure it to listen to [dynamic configuration changes](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/quick-start/configuration-dynamic-filesystem#dynamic-resources). The source for the dynamic configuration should be a shared volume between both your application container and the sidecar proxy container.
After your application started and allocated the dynamic port you can now automatically create the configuration for the envoy proxy and save it in the shared volume. The same source envoy is listening to due to the aforementioned configuration.
Envoy itself acts as a reverse proxy and can listen statically on port 8080 (or any other port you like) and routes the incoming network traffic to your application with dynamic port by calling *localhost:<dynamic-port>*.

Unfortunately I don't have any predefined configuration for this use case but if you need some inspiration you can take a look at [istio](https://github.com/istio/istio) - they use something quite similar.

Comment: Thank you @BeWu. Could you please explain more "Regarding the dynamic configuration of the proxy you could e.g. use shared pod volumes"? and if you have an example of such implementation? Thanks

Comment: @JackLehman I updated the answer and described how it works in more detail.

Comment: Best solution, takes some effort, but will definitly work!

Answer (score 0):

As gohm'c mentioned there is no built in way to do this.

As a workaround you can run a script to adjust the service:

1. Start the application and retrieve the choosen random port from the application
2. Modify the Kubernetes service, loadbalancer, etc. with the new port

The downside of this is that if the port changes there will be short delay to update the service afterwards.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing which is not very practical :(

Comment: Why is this not practical?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

1. Deploy and start your application in a Kubernetes cluster.
2. run `kubectl exec <pod name here> -- netstat -tulpn | grep "application name"` to identify the port number associated with your application.
3. run `kubectl port-forward <pod name here> <port you like>:<random application port>` to access the pod of your application.

Would this work for you?

Edit. This is very similar to @Lukas Eichler's response.